# Split a string to its subwords

Tags: sql, split, cpu-word, string-matching, substring

---

Every letter has a value
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i   j    k    l   m   n   o   p   q   r    s   t   u    v   w   x   y   z
1  2  3  4  5  6 7  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

---

TableA
String                  Length    Value                        Subwords
exampledomain      13          132         #example-domain#example-do-main#
creditcard               10           85                 #credit-card#credit-car-d#

---

TableB
Words           Length           Value
example           7                    76
do                    2                    19
main                4                     37
domain             6                    56
credit               6                    59
card                4                     26
car                  3                     22
d                     1                      4

---

**Explanation**
TableA has string based over milion rows, and it will be new added 100k rows/daily to tableA.
And also "string" column has no whitespaces

TableB has words based over milion rows,there is every letter and words in 1-2 languages

**What i want to do**
i want to split strings in TableA to its subwords, as you see in example; "creditcard" i search in TableB all words and try to find which words when comes together matches the string

**What i did,and couldnt solve my question**
i took the string and JOIN the TableB with **INNER JOINS** i made 2-3 times INNER JOINS because there can be 3word 4word strings too, and that WORKED!! but it takes too much time even doing it for 100-200 strings. Guess i want to do it for 100k/everyday???

**Now what i try to do**
i gave values to everyletter as you see above,
Took the strings one by one and from their including letters i count the value of strings..
And the same for the words too in TableB..
Now i have every string in TableA and everyword in TableB with their VALUES..
_
1- i will take the string,length and value of it (Exmple; creditcard - 10 - 85)
2- and make a search in TableB to find the possible words when they come together, with their SUM(length), and SUM(value) matches the strings length and value, and write theese possibilities to a new column.
At last even their sum of length and sum of values matches each other there can be some posibilities that doesnt match the whole string i will elliminate theese ones (Example; **"doma-in"** can be **"moda-in"** too and their lengths and values are same but not same words)

---

I dont know but,i guess with that value method i can solve the time proplem??? , or if there is another ways to do that, i will be gratefull taking your advices.
Thanks

Comment: My question is why is anyone bothering to save such data in such a useless format?  Instead of trying to find a solution for searching why aren't you finding a solution of saving the data in a more useful format?

Comment: if i was creating the whole data, ofcourse i wont save it like that, and then try to split it! - the strings are domainnames and you know that domainnames are at that format

Comment: Ah, that makes a little more sense then.  Be careful about penisland!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the solutions recursively by looking always at the next letter. For example for the word **DOMAIN**

1. D - no
2. DO - is a word!

   1. M - no
   2. MA - no
   3. MAI - no
   4. MAIN - is a word!

      1. No more letters --> **DO + MAIN**
3. DOM - is a word!

   1. A - no
   2. AI - no
   3. AIN - no
   4. Finished without result
4. DOMA - no
5. DOMAI - no
6. DOMAIN - is a word!

   1. No more letters --> **DOMAIN**

Comment: is that possible to try that with sql query in SMSS? Should i do it with IF-EXISTS, i am new, could you give an example and i try to find it, Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with sql query in SMSS.